# UIScrollView zoom around point

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView, and when the user pinches, I want to zoom around a certain point (not necessarily content center, and not necessarily pinch center).

What would be the best way to go about this?

I've tried experimenting with transforms etc. quite a lot, but never seemed to get it right.

I'm open for all kinds of solutions.